# Change Background and block hover by onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have trouble with JS, I can not solve the problem myself that.
I want that if I click on #footerblock that the background of #footerblock changes and then that footer loses his "hover effect".

```
<script>
/* i want that footer does still there but di want that footer has no a hover effect*/

</script>
<footer class="hover">
   <center>
      <table id="footer"></table>
      <a href="">Entwickler</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="">Datenschutzrichtlinie</a>
      <a href="">AGB</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="">Nutzungsbedingungen</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;
      <a href="">Partner</a>
   </center>
</footer>
<span onClick="block()" id="footerblock"></span>
```

I guess my css is not important, but I have to fiddle packed inside.

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8F6xG/)**

I´m sorry for my English

Comment: background change means only change color of background not change position like hover effect

Comment: allright or background image

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8F6xG/1/). When the block is clicked, the background becomes blue and there would be no hover effect. On a second click, it would go back to original state.

Comment: close but i want that the background of #footerblock changes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below. (Note: I am assuming you are using jQuery as it is tagged in question).

Basically what we are doing is that whenever the `#footerblock` is clicked, we add/remove a new class to the footer and remove the existing `hover` class from it. We do this because your `:hover` effect is coded in CSS like `.hover:hover` so removing the `hover` class will make sure that the `:hover` style will not be applied.

In addition we are also toggling a `block_clicked` class to the `#footerblock` to change its `background-color`.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#footerblock').on('click', function() {
        $('footer').toggleClass('clicked'); //toggling a new class on click to change background
        $('footer').toggleClass('hover'); //toggling the hover class because your `:hover` pseudo is attached to it.
        $(this).toggleClass('block_clicked'); //to add a custom style to the block when clicked.
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.clicked{
    background-color: blue;
}

#footerblock.block_clicked{
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8F6xG/4/)

**EDIT (Updated based on MLeFevre's comment):** Modified the css rule to `#footerblock.block_clicked` to do away with the usage of `!important`.

Comment: You could just do something like `#footerblock.block_clicked` instead of resorting to important

Comment: @MLeFevre +1 to that comment. Yes, that would be much better. Will change it in a minute :)

Comment: @Harry the Script have to be in JS can u change ur code so that my editor can read it right. My bowser says that $ not defined

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML: Have you included the jQuery library before this script?

Comment: no i have never work with jQuery before because of that i cannot handle with that

Comment: No worries, give me a few minutes and I will give a vanilla JS version

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML: Check [this version](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8F6xG/6/). Written a bit hastily so might not be the optimized version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8F6xG/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#footerblock').on('click',function(){
        $('footer.hover').toggleClass('andClicked');
    });
});
```

also added this css line on line 40

```
footer.hover.andClicked,
```